# PHP Echo Empty Check with Photos

Tags: php

i have issue with my php code .

First i have Database with Photo link then i add this with echo .

I Fill the Database with /upload/photo-1.png or what ever from the User !

```
<?php echo$photo; ?>
```

I add this with :

```
<?php if(!empty($photo)) {echo 'uploads/photodefault.png'; } ?>
```

Comment: ...keep going. You didn't say what the problem is or if any errors at all, given if you're checking for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write like this

```
<?php if(!empty($photo)) 
       {
          echo $photo; 
        } 
?>
```

Edit 1:

If photo is not empty then it will show link.

Comment: Can you explain why this is the way

Comment: i think @Markus Blubb want like this if photo is not empty then it will show that link

Comment: Then add the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
<?php

if(empty($photo)) {
    echo "uploads/photodefault.png";
} else {
    echo $photo;
}

?>
```

With an `<img>` tag example

```
<img src="<?php if(empty($photo)) { echo "uploads/photodefault.png"; } else { echo $photo; } ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
    if ($photo != ''){
    echo $photo;
    }else{
      echo "uploads/photodefault.png";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php if(!empty($photo)) { echo $photo; } else { echo 'default/default_large.png'; } ?>
```

This fixed my issue.

Comment: Please do not post a thank you as an answer. Add a comment under the answer if you wish to say thank you.